# Equalities of cardinal numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I need prove that:

> $2^{\aleph_{0}}=n^{\aleph_{0}}=\aleph_{0}^{\aleph_{0}}=c^{\aleph_{0}}=c$, for $n\geq2$. Where $c$ is the continuum.

I know that $2^{\aleph_{0}}\leq n^{\aleph_{0}}\leq\aleph_{0}^{\aleph_{0}}\leq c^{\aleph_{0}}$ and $2^{\aleph_{0}}=c$ then if $c^{\aleph_{0}}\leq c$ I'll can show what I want. Anybody know how I can do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** $(\kappa^\lambda)^\mu=\kappa^{\lambda\cdot\mu}$ for any three cardinals, $\kappa,\lambda,\mu$.

Comment: The purpose of the hint is to show that $c^{\aleph_{0}}\leq c$? Because I could not see it.

Comment: Well, it should direct you to equality. But sure, if $\kappa=\lambda$ then $\kappa\leq\lambda$ as well.

Comment: You have another hint?

Comment: Yes, look at your question and ask yourself where you can apply my hint in the most helpful way.

Comment: If I put $\kappa=c$, $\lambda=\aleph_{0}$ I don't know who $\mu$.

Comment: Look again at the definition of $c$.

Comment: $c=\vert \mathbb{R} \vert$.

Comment: No, look again. It's right there in your question. You already *know* it.

Comment: Ok. $c=2^{\aleph_{0}}$.

Comment: And now think again, what are $\kappa,\lambda$ and $\mu$ here?

Comment: $c=2^{\aleph_{0}}=2^{\aleph_{0} . \aleph_{0}}=(2^{\aleph_{0}})^{\aleph_{0}}=c^{\aleph_{0}}$. :D

Comment: There you go! Isn't it better than me telling you the answer flat out? :-)

Comment: Yes, I was worried because English is not my mother language and you could get annoyed that I didn't express myself right. Thanks was helpful!!